# How to run as sudo when debugging app from VS 2017 to Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cross-compiling

I'm using VS2017 on my Windows PC and trying to debug on a Linux machine. 
My app needs to run with higher permissions so how do I tell the debugger to run `sudo` with my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround method.

Sudo instruction for my situation is for open the TTY port. so I use the "chmod o+rw /dev/ttyUSB0" to get the permission of access in VS2017.

VS2017 open tty port successfully without sudo.

You can find which one lib or tools you have to with permission, and then change it through the "chmod" instruction.

Thanks.

[Open TTY OK in VS2017 Cross Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3LF5.jpg)